# Using Autohotkey - Reading webpage content source without Control + U

Tags: autohotkey, website

I have a project going where I need to look at the source of any general website, but I usually have to look at the source for key words. I use the shortcut <kbd>Control + U</kbd>. Then I proceed with <kbd>Control + A</kbd>, <kbd>Control + C</kbd>, then read the contents via %clipboard%. I want to alleviate from opening the page and closing it.

Is there a way to view this page without opening it? I have some programming skills so that isn't an issue. Since I am not terribly familiar with AHK, there might be something I am not aware of.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just happened to be working on something similar. I do this with a temporary text file. I do use the clipboard, but I don't open the page itself to view the "source".

Here is how it's done.

```
clipboard :=                      ; clear the clipboard
send {F6}                         ; select url of current page
sleep 50                          ; not mandatory -- 50ms
send ^{c}
clipwait, 2
sleep 50

URL=%clipboard%                   ; extra step, placing clip into var
send {F6}                         ; release url in url bar.


UrlDownloadToFile %URL%, file.tmp ; Where tile.tmp is local to your AHK
                                  ; There is now a file to read from

FileRead, var_text, file.tmp   ; There is now a variable to read text
                                  ;   places all text from page into var
```

Comment: that was quick. looks promising

Comment: Worked perfectly!